# remove reply buttons from wp comments

Tags: wordpress, comments, reply

I need that, anyone can post a question, but answers to the questions should only be posted by admins from the wp dashboad, thats why i need to remove the reply buttons from the comments.

Thank you

Comment: right click on Reply, go to inspect element, then check the class name, go to Customize - Additional CSS - Type ".classname{display:none!important;}"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

right click on Reply, go to inspect element, then check the class name of , go to Customize - Additional CSS - Type 
`.classname{
display:none!important;
}`
note: classname should be button's class name.